# cp: cannot create regular file 'proc/filename': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, copy, cp

Im trying to copy  **Source:** /home/user/filename **destination:** /proc

running cmd as root from "/" location:

> cp /home/user/filename proc/

getting the error:

> cp: cannot create regular file 'proc/filename': No such file or directory

/proc dir permissions is set to:

> drwxr-xr-x 91 root root     0 Dec 31  1969 proc

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: I believe I found the answer in: 

The /proc filesystem contains a illusionary filesystem. It does not exist on a disk. Instead, the kernel creates it in memory.

so I am assuming thats is why I cannot copy anything to this directory?